# Spring config server returns json response with resolved paths - how to avoid this?

Tags: json, spring, spring-cloud-config, configserver, spring-cloud-config-server

I have a .yml file like this in my gitlab server

```
   holidays:  
   US:  
     - 03/19/2020  
     - 03/20/2020  
     - 05/18/2020
```

the config server reads the above yml and returns something the response like this

```
{"name":"*****","profiles":["simpleyml"],"label":null,"version":"*****","state":null,"propertySources":[{"name":"https://*****.com/****.git/application-simpleyml.yml",source":{"holidays.US[0]":"03/19/2020","holidays.US[1]":"03/20/2020"}
```

I would need the config server to return the "source" part like the below instead

```
{"name":"*****","profiles":["simpleyml"],"label":null,"version":"*****","state":null,"propertySources":[{"name":"https://*****.com/****.git/application-simpleyml.yml","source":
  {
    "holidays": {
      "US": [
        "03/19/2020",
        "03/20/2020"
       ]
    }
  }
```

Could someone please help me out on this?

Comment: Can you post your yml file

Comment: You may be want to format your yaml file in the question as code fragment so no misunderstanding

Comment: Thanks @KavithakaranKanapathippillai edit my question above to have a better understanding. added the entire response from config server.. please see the "source" section in the response. thats the content that config-server reads and represents the yml file

Comment: @VJohn any updates that you have for the question you have posted on the json hierarchy being concatenated ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

Input YAML

```
source:
 holidays:
  US:
    - 03/19/2020
    - 03/20/2020
```

Returned JSON

```
{ "source": { "holidays": { "US": [ "03/19/2020", "03/20/2020" ] } } }
```

I think this matches your requirement

Comment: I am not able to find difference, can you point what's the difference between your requirement and what I have posted

Comment: Thanks for this. but its the same output

another ex:
my yml file

application-simpleyml.yml

-----
holidays:
  US: city
-----

Spring config server returns

----------------------
{"name":"*****","profiles":["simpleyml"],"label":null,"version":"***","state":null,"propertySources":[{"name":"https://*****.com/****.git/application-simpleyml.yml","source":{"holidays.US":"city"}}]}
-------------


See the source content.. the Yaml path is still resolved.. What i need is something like this
-----------
{"source":{"holidays": {"US":"city"}}
-------

pls see the diff in source

Comment: If you will directly request it from Spring Config Server output will come in this way only. Not possible to get just source. Only option is after getting the response parse the JSON. Spring Config Server is their to communicate with microservices only.

Comment: Sorry, may be my question was confusing. basically, its not like i only need "source". 

Config server reads yaml and returns with resolved paths like "holidays.US:***"

all i need is just avoid this resolving paths and return the content like this "holidays: { US: ** }}